# Navigate to one anonymous bookmark

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Suppose I have only one anonymous bookmark added using F11. Can I navigate to it using keyboard? I know I navigate to it using SHIFT+F11, but I want to navigate to it using keyboard

Comment: you could use Shift+F11 and then Enter

Comment: @arghtype, thanks, that is an option. But if I have numbered bookmarks, they come before anonymous bookmarks

Answer (score 1):

With anonymous bookmarks the Next/Previous Bookmark should work. Check your hotkeys under Navigate | Bookmarks menu or assign one.